# Getting innerhtml value into the variable

Tags: javascript

I am getting a value by using `document.getElementById("forloop").innerHtml`. And I am displaying that value in the file with some div id as

```
<div id="forloop"></div>.
```

But I want to assign that value to a variable in the file. Can you please how can I assign to the variable?

Answer (score 18):

```
var myInnerHtml = document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML;
```

In most browsers, the property is named `innerHTML` (with HTML in all-caps), not innerHtml, so watch for that.

Comment: all browsers, not most browsers

Comment: @mplungjan I always leave a little wiggle room where I can. :)

Answer (score 11):

If you want the value along with the HTML tags then you will use:

```
var x=document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML;
```

Or if you want only the value then you will use:

```
var x=document.getElementById("forloop").innerText;
```

Comment: innerText is not supported by all browsers that support innerHTML - sniff for textContent and give innerText if not there

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if i understand right, maybe this?

```
var variable = document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know where the strech is:

```
var x = document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the innerHTML of `<div id="forloop"></div>` added through JavaScript? If so, you might want to make sure that the `var myInnerHtml = document.getElementById("forloop").innerHTML` gets executed after the innerHTML has been added.