# How to get value of HTML element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

so I'm having trouble with getting the value of a specific field in my code - I made this pretty simple example to show my problem, here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c3jtg60v/

The HTML:

```
<p id="theInput">
   desired-value
</p>
```

The Javascript:

```
var value = document.getElementById("theInput").value;
console.log(value);
```

As is, I have assigned a **p** element with an id of "theInput", and in it I have the desired value, that I want to make use of in my javascript.

At the moment, all I'm trying to do is console.log the value, but when I do this, all i get logged in the console is 'undefined'. What I really want to get logged to the console is "desired value",

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting innerhtml value into the variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492671/getting-innerhtml-value-into-the-variable)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268806/how-to-get-the-label-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.value` refers to a `value` property, which cannot be set for a **P** tag. If you want the inner text of a `html` tag, you could do this:

```
var value = document.getElementById("theInput").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Better to use innerText instead innerHTML if you wants to get only text, if you wants to get tag also use innerHTML

Comment: No, innerText is not supported by all browsers, while innerHTML is supported everywhere.

Comment: InnerText is supported by almost all modern browsers https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
var value = document.getElementById("theInput").innerHTML;
console.log(value);
```

Comment: Please consider adding context to your answer

Answer (score 2):

It should be `textContent` not `value`.

```
var value = document.getElementById("theInput").textContent;
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Better to use **innerText** instead **innerHTML** if you wants to get only text, if you wants to get tag also use innerHTML.

**innerText**: Give you only text

**innerHTML**: Give you text and HTML

```js
 var value = document.getElementById("theInput").innerText;
 console.log(value);
 value = document.getElementById("theInput").innerHTML;
 console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="theInput">
     desired-value
     <span>test</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var msg = document.getElementById('theInput').innerHTML;
alert(msg);
```

```html
<p id="theInput">
   desired-value
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use innerHTML:

```
var value = document.getElementById("theInput").innerHTML;
console.log(value);
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c3jtg60v/1/)

Answer (score 1):

`.value` does not return the inner text. You should use `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`. Use one of the following

```
var value1 = document.getElementById("theInput").innerHTML;
console.log(value1);

var value2 = document.getElementById("theInput").textContent;
console.log(value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

.value property in java script is only for returning  values of  the tag used for "forms" such as input tag.
What you wanna do is use innerHTML property which returns the value of content inside the html tag.
 So

```
var value = document.getElementById("theInput").innerHTML;
console.log(value);
```

Would be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

There is also another solution if the HTML Element you are looking for, **does not have** an "**id**" tag.
Officially if you would like to take the "value" of the element, you would do something like this:

```
var value = document.getElementById("someId").value
```

But sometimes ther is no "**id**" of that element, so you can use something like this:

```
var element =  document.getElementsByClassName("className") as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLElement>
```

This will return a collection of the HTML elements. And then you simply chose the element you want, by it's index and take the value like that:

```
var value = element[index]['value']
```