# object[htmltablelement] instead of string of table html

Tags: javascript

I have a table and if I want to get its markup via JavaScript, I am using `document.getElementById('')`, this works but doesn't give it to me as a string. So if I do `String(document.getElementById(''))` then it returns as `object[htmltablelement]`

My desired output is "<table..."

The reason it needs to be in String format is because I will be putting it into a PDF, and if it is raw HTML, I will get errors.

Comment: Indeed, getELEMENTbyId returns an element, not a string. You need to extract the text out of this element. Try .innerHTML?

Comment: What about using `document.getElementById('tableId').outerHTML`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get value of HTML element in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288562/how-to-get-value-of-html-element-in-javascript)